# In a day on Mars vs In the day on Mars

Tags: articles, generic-noun-phrases

> On Mars, you'll get extra time **in the day** to do the things you want to do--like sleep in! Martian days are about half an hour longer than Earth days. But that's nothing compared to the extra time you'll get in a year--687 days versus only 365 days on Earth.

The above is an excerpt from a kid book and can also be found on the website below:
https://www.windows2universe.org/kids_space/lifeonmars.html

I wonder why the definite article was used in this case.

> You will have extra time in a day on Mars

also sounds ok to me.

Maybe "a day" indicate "a single day on Mars"?

I am so lost here and would be really grateful if someone can help me understand
this issue.
Thank you

Comment: I think that both ways work here. With **the**, the sentence is referring to the "generic" day. With **a**, it's referring to "any day". I've added the "*generic-noun-phrases*" tag, you can look at question concerning this topic.

Comment: in the day is the same as during the day, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I believe in this case "the day" is being used as the daytime hours, the opposite of night where "a day" generally refers to the entire 24 hours, night and day.